# How do I return null in typescript

Tags: typescript

In the following I need to return null in the case UserAction.LOGOUT_REQUESTED.  How an I do it or is there a better way to do it?

```
public static reducer(state: ILoginReducerState = UserReducer.initialState, action: ILogInAction): ILoginReducerState {
    switch (action.type) {
 case UserAction.LOGOUT_REQUESTED:
            return null}
```

The ILoginReducerState is defined as follows

```
export interface IlogIn
{ 
userName : string,
password:string,
error:boolean
}

export interface ILoginReducerState 
{
readonly loading: boolean
readonly currentUser: IlogIn
readonly errors?: string
}
```

Right now I am having the error [ts] Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ILoginReducerState'.

```
private static readonly initialState: ILoginReducerState = {
    currentUser: {
        error:false,
        password:'',
        userName:'',
    },
    errors:'',
    loading: false,
};
```

Comment: So return `ILoginReducerState | null`?

Comment: That's probably because you have `strictNullChecks` enabled. Either you can disable that or you can do as @zerkms suggest

Comment: @zerkms, with ILoginReducerState | null, I am having the error  [ts] Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ILoginReducerState'.
[ts] 'ILoginReducerState' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: where does the number type comes from? Can u determinate where it comes from? It must be from from the ILoginReducerState because null has no type is there something missing?

Comment: Nothing is missing.  It represents all the code, exactly the same.

Comment: Is there a reason to return `null` in reducer?

Comment: Instead of returning `null` in logout, you should return something like: `{ currentUser: null, loading: false, errors: '' }`, and then in out `ILoginReducerState` interface, `currentUser` should be set to  `IlogIn | null`.

Comment: If I do as @saadq says, I get the error:Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'IlogIn'.
IAuthenticateReducerState.ts(11, 14): The expected type comes from property 'currentUser' which is declared here on type 'ILoginReducerState' and [tslint] Forbidden bitwise operation